# Controller not processing params for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save a record to a Bookings table that has foreign keys from Schedules and Users table.

Here is the schema:

```
create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "seats"
    t.integer "base_price"
    t.integer "total_price"
    t.string "status"
    t.integer "schedules_id", null: false
    t.integer "users_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["schedules_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_schedules_id"
    t.index ["users_id"], name: "index_bookings_on_users_id"
  end

  create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "departure", null: false
    t.string "destination", null: false
    t.integer "seats_available", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "price"
    t.datetime "date_time"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", null: false
    t.string "password_digest", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "firstname", null: false
    t.string "lastname", null: false
  end
```

Schedule and User `has_many :bookings` and Booking `belongs_to :schedules` and `:users`.

My view in `bookings/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@book, url: booking_path, local: true) do |f| %>
  <% @books.each do |data| %>
    <%= data.departure %>
    <%= data.destination %>
    <%= data.formatted_date_time %>
    <%= data.seats_available %>
    <%= data.price %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :base_price, value: data.price %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :seats %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :total_price %>
    <%= f.submit "Book" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it but this is my attempt. Assume the hidden fields has a way to get the data, because I cut out the code that does it since I can see the params being passed in the Command Prompt.

My routes:

```
get 'booking', to: 'bookings#new'
post 'booking', to: 'bookings#create'
```

My `BookingsController`:

```
def new
  @books = Schedule.where(id: params[:book_id])
  @book = Booking.new
end

def create
  @book = Booking.new(booking_params)
  if @book.save
      flash[:success] = 'success'
      redirect_to root_path
  end
end

private

def booking_params
  params.require(:booking).permit(:base_price, :seats, :total_price)
end
```

In the command prompt it does display the parameters `{ "booking"=>{"base_price"=>"80", "seats"=>"2", "total_price"=>"160"}, "commit"=>"Book"}`.  The problem is that after that it now loads `bookings/create.html.erb` without saving the params. It somehow doesn't do the `if @book.save` part. Also I don't know how I can put the foreign keys or the `:status` variable or do I even need to. I appreciate the help!

Comment: You should not be passing the price in a hidden input unless you want to let malicous users book stuff for 1$. Instead you should just be passing an ID and calculating prices on the backend. Also `@books` is a collection of Schedule instances and `@book` is a `Booking` - WAT?

Comment: As to why this doesn't work - you're creating a single form but inputs for each record you're iterating across. Since the inputs have the same name attribute the last one will just overwrite everything else in the parameters. Instead you want to iterate and create a form for each record.

Comment: Can you show me in code? Sorry I'm quite inexperienced when it comes to handling models.

Comment: Not really. This requires an almost total rewrite and the requirements are very unclear.